# How can I make it so that more than one ID will trigger using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following:

```
$('#editMenu', '#createContent', '#editContent')
    .click(function () {
        var $link = $(this);
        if ($link.attr('data-disabled') === 'no') {
            $link.attr('data-disabled', 'yes');
            adminDialog($link);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

However it seems like clicking on any of these does not work. Am I setting it up correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying is [`multiple selector`](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) which should be written as a single string with comma separated selector. See below,

Change

```
$('#editMenu', '#createContent', '#editContent')
```

to

```
$('#editMenu, #createContent, #editContent')
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery allows for [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) like so:

> jQuery('selector1, selector2, selectorN')

so you would need:

```
$('#editMenu, #createContent, #editContent')
```

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order. An alternative to this combinator is the .add()
>   method.